# How to rename column name on basis of previous column output?

Tags: mysql

I am writing select query for ledger in which i have to use value of first column as name of second column. Forexample

```
Select 
IF(`A` > '10', 'Aisgreater', 'Aisnotgreater') AS output,
result AS ???? 
From example table
```

I have tried this but its giving me error, wondering if there is another way to do it, my PHP code require this. the following query is just example not actual scenario.

```
Select 
IF(`A` > '10', 'Aisgreater', 'Aisnotgreater') AS output,
result AS (SELECT output) 
From example table
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. Sample data and desired result (As text) would help.

Comment: What if you change `AS output` to `AS result` instead?